# MySQL query PHP and PDF shows only first character

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I am running the following query:

```
$sql_1 = "SELECT `mb_transactions`.`TransactionID` AS `TXID` FROM `mb_transactions`";
$data_1 = $db->query($sql_1);
$count = count($data_1, COUNT_RECURSIVE);
if ($count > 1){
        foreach ($data_1 as $transaction_1) {
        $pdf->Cell($colWidths4[0], $pdf->fontHeight($fontSize), $transaction_1['TXID'], $border, 0, 'L');
        $pdf->Cell($colWidths4[1], $pdf->fontHeight($fontSize), '', $border, 0, 'L');
        $pdf->Cell($colWidths4[2], $pdf->fontHeight($fontSize), '', $border, 0, 'L');
        $pdf->Cell($colWidths4[3], $pdf->fontHeight($fontSize), '', $border, 0, 'L');
        $pdf->Ln();
        }
}
```

However I am only getting the first character from the result that shows. When I do a var_dump($transaction_1) I am seeing string(2) "11"     ...etc 
Appreciate any insight anyone cares to share

Comment: If this is a MySQLi::query() call, you have not fetched a row from your result, and `$data_1` is a result resource.

Comment: When it's string value (something like `MySQLi result resource 11` is accessed with array indices `[]`, you get individual characters of that string.  Let us know which MySQL API is being used by `query()` and we'll know what `$data_1` actually contains.

Comment: The contents of $colWidths4 may be useful also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this instead for each

```
while ($data = $data_1->fetchRow(DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC)) {

}
```